# Is it possible to view private events within a team repo?

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

Been playing around with the Github v3 API.

I was wondering if it was possible to see private events within a team repository I belong to if I am authenticated.

I see on the docs that with the `/users/:username/events` endpoint, it'll only show your own private events. Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are authenticated the `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/events` endpoint will do what you expect - see events associated with a repository.

Documentation: https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-repository-events

There are also repository issue events `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/events` which are a slightly different format.

Documentation: https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-issue-events-for-a-repository

Comment: This could require authentication. If it does, one way to authenticate is by using a personal token. Follow this guide: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token and then add to your curl `-u myuser:mytoken` to get the results.